# Using select option embeded in a table to dynamically change a user role to different roles via JQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to dynamically allow the user to change a user role by using a select tag within a table which, when change triggers an event, record the changes in JQuery and send the changes to PHP via AJAX. From the image attached, the only select tag which fires an event is the one in the first row of the table shown. Any changes made to other rows does not fired an event as shown by one of the images with the console.log information. I am trying to allow whoever has the rights to change a specific user role by selecting the adajacent select option within the same table row which is send via AJAX to change the field in the database. I have posted this question before however Wesley Smith recommended I do a new post. Anyone please feel free to comment.

```
<?php
require_once('../../private/initialize.php');
require_login();
$admins = find_all_admins();
?>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['message']) )
{
    echo "<div> </div><h5 style=\"color: #08ff00\">". $_SESSION['message'] ."</h5> </div>";
}
unset($_SESSION['message']);
//if(isset($SESSION['image_msg']))
//{
//    echo "<div> </div><h5 style=\\" . $_SESSION['image_msg'] . "</#ffffff> </div>";
//}
?>

    <form action="" method='post'>

        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <!--        <div id="bulkOptionContainer" class="col-xs-4">-->
            <!---->
            <!--            <select class="form-control" name="bulk_options" id="">-->
            <!--                <option value="">Select Options</option>-->
            <!--                <option value="published">Publish</option>-->
            <!--                <option value="draft">Draft</option>-->
            <!--                <option value="delete">Delete</option>-->
            <!--                <option value="clone">Clone</option>-->
            <!--            </select>-->
            <!---->
            <!--        </div>-->

            <div class="col-xs-4" id="addnew" >

                <!--            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Apply">-->
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="staff.php?source=add_staff">Add New</a>

            </div>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <!--            <th><input id="selectAllBoxes" type="checkbox"></th>-->
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <?php while ($all_admins = mysqli_fetch_assoc($admins)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo url_for('../images/staff/'.$all_admins['image'])?>" onerror="this.src='<?php echo url_for('../images/staff/profile.jpg') ?>'" style="border:1px solid #ddd;border-radius:2px; box-shadow: #4a5f63; height: 70px;width: 70px"></td>
                    <td><?php echo h($all_admins['first_name']) ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo h($all_admins['last_name']) ?></td>
                    <td><a class='btn btn-info' href="staff.php?source=show_staff&staff_id=<?php echo h($all_admins['id']) ?>"> <?php echo h($all_admins['email']) ?> </a></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                                $role = $all_admins['role'];
                                switch ($role){
                                    case 'DE':
                                        echo "Data Entry";
                                        break;
                                    case 'GU':
                                        echo "General User";
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        echo "Administrator";
                                        break;
                                }
                        ?>
                        <span>
                            <select class="urole" name="role[]">
                                            <option value="Admin" <?php echo ($role == 'Admin')?'selected':'' ?> >Admin</option>
                                            <option value="DE" <?php echo ($role == 'DE')?'selected':'' ?> >Data Entry</option>
                                            <option value="GU" <?php echo ($role == 'GU')?'selected':'' ?> >General User</option>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><a class='btn btn-info' href="staff.php?source=edit_staff&staff_id=<?php echo h($all_admins['id']) ?>">Edit</a></td>
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php //echo $post_id ?>">

                        <?php
                        echo '<td><input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"></td>';

                        ?>

                    </form>

                </tr>
                <!---->
                <!--            <td><input class='checkBoxes' type='checkbox' name='checkBoxArray[]' value='-->
            <?php } //echo $post_id; ?><!--'></td>-->

            <?php
            mysqli_free_result($admins);

            // echo "<td><a rel='$post_id' href='javascript:void(0)' class='delete_link'>Delete</a></td>";


            // echo "<td><a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete'); \" href='posts.php?delete={$post_id}'>Delete</a></td>";
            //            echo "<td><a href='posts.php?reset={$post_id}'>{$post_views_count}</a></td>";
            //            echo "</tr>";

            //}


            ?>


            </tbody>
        </table>

    </form>


<?php

//if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
//
//    $the_post_id = escape($_POST['post_id']);
//
//    $query = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE post_id = {$the_post_id} ";
//    $delete_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
//    header("Location: /cms/admin/posts.php");
//
//
//}
//
//
//if (isset($_GET['reset'])) {
//
//    $the_post_id = escape($_GET['reset']);
//
//    $query = "UPDATE posts SET post_views_count = 0 WHERE post_id = $the_post_id  ";
//    $reset_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
//    header("Location: posts.php");
//
//
//}


?>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        // $(".delete_link").on('click', function () {
        //
        //
        //     var id = $(this).attr("rel");
        //
        //     var delete_url = "posts.php?delete=" + id + " ";
        //
        //
        //     $(".modal_delete_link").attr("href", delete_url);
        //
        //
        //     $("#myModal").modal('show');
        //});

        $('.urole').on('change',function (e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var val = $(".urole option:selected").val();
                console.log(val);
                console.log(e);

            // $("#urole").on('click', function(){
            //     v
            // });

            //displayData(val);
        });

        $("#urole").ready(function (){
            var val = $("#urole option:selected").val();
            console.log(val);
            //displayData(val);
        });

    });
    function displayData(query){
        $.ajax({
            url:"enrolled_learners/enrol_learner_provider.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function (data)
            {
                //console.log(data);
                $('#q-provider').html(data);
            }
        });
    }



    <?php
    //if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
    //
    //        unset($_SESSION['message']);
    //
    //    }

    ?>


</script>
User Interface and Console log[enter image description here][1]
[User Interface][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector selects all with the class `urole`, you just want to select the one that changed, since you're in the change handler for that element you can access it via the `this` keyword.

```
    $('.urole').on('change',function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var val = this.value;
            console.log(val);
            console.log(e);
            displayData(val);
    });
```

Comment: thanks. I have been struggling to find a solution for something this simple, using this keyword. It is working now.